# Unblock context menu: difference between direct input of JS to the address bar and a bookmark

Tags: javascript

I'm scrutinizing the phenomenon of blicking the context menu via JavaScript.

This is how such a menu can be blocked:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

And I've read in an article that such blocking can be reset if in the address bar we input:

```
javascript:void(document.oncontextmenu=null);
```

I tried in Chrome under Windows. This excertpt can't be input as a whole. It looks like this in the address bar

```
void(document.oncontextmenu=null);
```

And then it starts searching for this string in Google. Well it it not what we are looking for.

But if we create a bookmark with that desired code, and use it on the target page, it works perfectly. In other words, it unblocks the context menu.

Threrfore two questions:
1. What is the difference between manual insertion of the script above into the address bar and the use of the bookmark?
2. Can this script be used not in the bookmark to achieve the desired result? Does it depend on the browser or what does it depend on?

Comment: Safari appears to not allow javascript in the address bar.  For chrome, it looks like it's a fight between interpreting it as a URL or something you want to search for.  I did notice that if I paste it in all at once, it drops 'javascript:'.  If I type it in manually and hit enter, it executes it.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, paste this into the chrome address bar and it will search for 'void(alert('foo'))'

```
javascript:void(alert('foo'))
```

Then, type it in manually, hit enter, and you'll get the alert.

Not sure what this answers, but I thought it's worth sharing.